# Convert bitmap to sepia in android

Tags: android, android-image

Is there any way to convert a Bitmap to sepia?
I know to convert to grayScale is to set the setSaturation in ColorMatrix.
But what about Sepia?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: What is your requirement exactly? You want an algorithm with different approach?

Comment: @aminography I wanted to give 250 reputation to one of the existing answers here because it solved my problem I was having today; but I still have 16 hours left before I can give that award.

Comment: Oh, nice job dude :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the answer, but maybe if some have other better solution..

```
public Bitmap toSephia(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
{        
    int width, height, r,g, b, c, gry;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
    int depth = 20;

    Bitmap bmpSephia = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpSephia);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setScale(.3f, .3f, .3f, 1.0f);   
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    for(int x=0; x < width; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y < height; y++) {
            c = bmpOriginal.getPixel(x, y);

            r = Color.red(c);
            g = Color.green(c);
            b = Color.blue(c);

            gry = (r + g + b) / 3;
            r = g = b = gry;

            r = r + (depth * 2);
            g = g + depth;

            if(r > 255) {
              r = 255;
            }
            if(g > 255) {
              g = 255;
            }
            bmpSephia.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(r, g, b));
        }
    }      
    return bmpSephia;
}
```

Comment: this is going to more processing time when the image pixel is more so any other way is there?

Comment: This methods fails on transparent pixels

Answer (score 21):

If you have instance of image then you can use ColorMartix to draw it in Sepia. Let me describe way how you can do this using Drawable.

```
public static void setSepiaColorFilter(Drawable drawable) {
  if (drawable == null)
    return;

  final ColorMatrix matrixA = new ColorMatrix();
  // making image B&W
  matrixA.setSaturation(0);

  final ColorMatrix matrixB = new ColorMatrix();
  // applying scales for RGB color values
  matrixB.setScale(1f, .95f, .82f, 1.0f);
  matrixA.setConcat(matrixB, matrixA);

  final ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrixA);
  drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
}
```

Sample project was moved from [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/steven_rudenko/colormatrix) to [GitHub](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ColorMartix). Please check [Release section](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ColorMartix/releases) to download APK binary to test without compiling.

[image]

Comment: how can I get ColorMatric for more effects, like neon, indiglow, aqua, vivid, etc,
waiting for related link/hint/guide...

Comment: You need find corresponding color matrix values to get these effect. Sorry but I don't know any resource where you can find it. Please post it here if you will find anything useful. Thanks

Comment: I found this for ColorMatrix, and set simillar values for my required color effects.
http://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide

Comment: It's actually pretty easy, just find the values based on the color's RGB values and you'll get any color you want. Once the saturation is set to 0, it'll combine the brightness of a pixel with the new color, and it'll just work. Although I'm answering something that was asked 6 years ago... :D

Answer (score 1):

I've improved on [the OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141150/convert-bitmap-to-sepia-in-android#4142155). This runs competitively fast when compared to [the `ColorMatrix` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141150/convert-bitmap-to-sepia-in-android#9149010), but producing a nicer brown tone. (in my opinion)

```
public Bitmap toSepiaNice(Bitmap color) {
    int red, green, blue, pixel, gry;
    int height = color.getHeight();
    int width = color.getWidth();
    int depth = 20;

    Bitmap sepia = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    color.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixel = pixels[i];

        red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        blue = pixel & 0xFF;

        red = green = blue = (red + green + blue) / 3;

        red += (depth * 2);
        green += depth;

        if (red > 255)
            red = 255;
        if (green > 255)
            green = 255;
        pixels[i] = (0xFF << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
    }
    sepia.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return sepia;
}
```