# Image duotone effect

Tags: android, image, image-effects

I have seen that there is EffectFactory in Android and it supports Duotone effect. But it only works on API level 14 and up.  
The problem is that I need the app to work from API level 11.
So my question is if there is a way to make Duotone image effect on Android below API 14?  
With my current code, I access every pixel, get its RGB and change it. But I don't know how duotone works. Here is my code:

```
public Bitmap doColorFilter(Bitmap src)
{
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);

            R = (int) (Color.red(pixel));
            G = (int) (Color.green(pixel));
            B = (int) (Color.blue(pixel));
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}
```

***EDIT:***
Sepia toning isn't working like I need it to. Here are three images:
1. original one.
2. one with modified sepia tone effect Der Golem linked
3.the one with duotone effect I need:
[image: original]

[image: Sepia effect]

[image: Duo tone]

Comment: Use a ColorMatrix. Here's an example (see the answer with 15 upvotes); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141150/convert-bitmap-to-sepia-in-android

Comment: I know about ColorMatrix. I am using it for some of the effects. But I can't make Duotone effect.

Comment: Duotone (toning) is like sepia toning (desaturation + color). Just change the color used for the sepia filter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duotone

Comment: Not working like I need it. Please see answer below with images.

Comment: I guess you have to combine 2 differently duotoned pictures to get the effect you are after.

Comment: And possibly use a mask (see `PorterDuffXferMode`) to blend them. See this example: http://android-er.blogspot.it/2013/08/merge-images-with-porterduffxfermode.html