# Create night vision effect to Camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I know all other stuff about creating and handling camera.

**I only want to know how to add a Night Vision effect to Camera View**.

**Or how could i create an effect ?**

To support a night vision I have no clue from where to start.

Comment: Simply greyscale your image and then virate it to green. For better performances, use a ColorMatrix.

Comment: What's a night vision effect?

Comment: @DaveNewton Like infrared (fake): all virated to black and green, I guess. At least, if you google `night vision` you het 4 images like that.

Comment: Here you will find a ["sepia toning" effect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9149010/2649012). Simply change the toning value to a bright green and you're done. The [effect itself](https://www.google.com/search?q=night+vision&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=615&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=4jspVfvpAcX3UsKVg6AP&ved=0CCMQsAQ). Optionally, you can superimpose a black round mask with a hole - or 2, to simulate a binocular.

Comment: What are your performance requirements?  To get high speed (e.g. 30fps) you'll probably need to use GLES. See e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: @DerGolem I want to add this to camera Preview at runtime. And when i take picture or record video that effect also added to pic or video.